# How to subscribe to screen dim event on linux

Tags: brightness, backlight

I have a script which corrects my screen brightness based on an ambient light sensor. I want it to stop changing my screen brightness when my screen dims as a result of user inactivity.

How can I subscribe to a screen dim event?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but [xautolock](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xautolock) looks promising for your case, if you're using X.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```shell
dbus-monitor interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties',member='PropertiesChanged' --profile | grep backlight
```